# An eigenvalue problem associated with the KdV equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the function $u(\xi,\tau)$ as the solution of KdV equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\tau}-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial\xi}+\delta^2\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial\xi^3}=0
$$
where $\delta$ is a constant.
I found a book which considers the associated eigenvalue problem
$$
6\delta^2\frac{\mathrm d^2\psi}{\mathrm d\xi^2}-u\psi=\lambda\psi
$$
Given a specific $\tau$ i.e. $u(\xi,\tau)$ we'll get an eigenvalue and corresponding solution $\psi$. The book claims that the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is independent of $\tau$:
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm d\lambda}{\mathrm d\tau}=0
$$
I used Mathematica to solve eigenvalue numerically for one soliton solution of $u$ and different $\tau$ and found it true, but I don't know how to prove it analytically. Anyone could help?

Comment: “I found a book” is rather useless information. It would be better to say *which* book it is. Anyway, the fact that you're asking about follows from the Lax representation for the KdV equation, as is explained in many (other) books. The original article by Lax is [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.3160210503), behind a paywall unfortunately, but you might find copies if you search the web for the title.